# passing a 2D array from python to swagger

Tags: python, multidimensional-array, swagger

I am confused by why this doesn't work.  Here is my swagger.yaml part where it defines what a result  is. The code that links to this returns an array of arrays:

> [[string,float],....]

when i switch this array to

> [string,string,...]

everything works.

```
results:
    type: "object"
    required:
    - "content"
    properties:
      content:
        type: "array"
        items:
          type: "array"
          items: {}
```

Not sure what is going on with the 2D array. The swagger keeps complaining:

> ```
> raise TypeError('Expected bytes') TypeError: Expected bytes
> ```

Comment: So your 2D array works but you receive a warning? Correct?

Comment: no it doesn't work. It gives an error.

Comment: Are you missing a comma? [[string,float],....] ?

Comment: that's what I meant to write. Just edited the text.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nested arrays were not permitted in swagger until 2.0.

If you are using 1.2 or earlier then you cannot directly nest arrays. See [section 4.3.3](http://docs.swagger.io/spec.html) of the 1.2 spec, specifically it indicates 'A container MUST NOT be nested in another container.'

Nested arrays are now allowed for 2.0, but my *limited* understanding is that the array elements must all be of the same type. This comes from the section named 'ITEMS OBJECT' about a third of the way down [the 2.0 spec](http://swagger.io/specification/).

I can't give you much useful advice beyond that. The github issues pages are quite interesting as a number of issues related to your problem are covered in a 'why not do it this way instead' type manner. [Issue 53](https://github.com/OAI/OpenAPI-Specification/issues/53) seems relevant to your problem, for example and also describes the nested array of array limitations (pre 2.0) and describes ways around it.

I hope this helps